# How'd I log the correct object value upon user clicking on the image?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm trying to display the `OfferName` upon user clicking on a list of images that each have their own data (an array of objects).

How can I make it so that upon user clicking on the image, the individual and correct  `OfferName` appears in the console?  I've tried to many ways to do this but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for all the tips/help.

Here's my js:

```
        var offerName = "";

        var img = document.getElementsByClassName('items');

        var userClicked = function userClicked() {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                offerName = array[i].OfferName;
                return offerName;
            }
        };

        for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            img[i].addEventListener('click', userClicked, false);
        }
       console.log(offerName);
```

Here's an example of on of the array's along with its corresponding object:

```
array  [22]
0    {5}
id    :    5933
desc    :    game
OfferName    :    blitz
Template    :    nonfeatured
SortIndex    :    0
```

Comment: Can you please write your offername array or object or what it is from where you are getting offername ?

Comment: @Sanmeet I don't think it matters where I'm getting it from.  I just want to display the `OfferName` that consistent with what image the user has clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is in your userClicked function. Your loop says to loop over an array called array, but inside the loop you have a return, so the loop will exit on the first iteration. What you should do is something like this:

```js
// As a point of order, img is not a very good descriptor of what
// this variable holds. I would recommend productLinks or something
// along those lines.
const img = document.getElementsByClassName('items');

// Instead of being a click handler, this takes the index of the 
// element and returns the correct offerName
function userClicked(i) {
  // array is a pretty bad variable name. It should probably be
  // productData.
  const offerName = array[i].OfferName;

  // This just logs the offerName. If you want to do something else
  // with it you should do it inside this function.
  console.log(offerName);
};

for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  // Create the click event handler inline here. Since i is a
  // primitive, the function () => userClicked(i) gets a different
  // value on every iteration. Also, the default value of useCapture
  // is false, so it doesn't need to be defined as false.
  img[i].addEventListener('click', () => userClicked(i));
}
```

Comment: Got it... makes sense, thanks!  But now I'm facing something else that's quite miniscule:  I'd like to declare a variable outside of `userClicked()` and pass that newly declared variable's value which will contain `offerName`'s value, onto another function's parameter.  However, whenever I try to do that, the value returns blank.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that the click event and the functions it calls are the only parts of the code that execute when the element is clicked. In the code from your question you will always get "" logged at the bottom, because that console.log only executes when the javascript is first loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.forEach()` loop to addEventListener to each element

Since you didn't provide any html i assumed one ( here i am using buttons intead of images but you can add class to img element it woll work fine )

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <!-- instead of buttons add class to img element --> 
  <button class="item">Item 1 </button>
  <button class="item">Item 2 </button>
  <button class="item">Item 3 </button>
</div>
```

**Js**

```
  var offers = [ {
    id: 5933,
    desc: "game",
    OfferName: "blitz",
    Template: "nonfeatured",
    SortIndex: 0
  }, {
    id: 5934,
    desc: "game",
    OfferName: "blitz  - 2",
    Template: "featured",
    SortIndex: 0
  }, {
    id: 5935,
    desc: "game",
    OfferName: "blitz  - 3",
    Template: "special",
    SortIndex: 0
  }];

  let img = document.querySelectorAll('.item');


  img.forEach((item, index)=> {
    item.onclick = ()=> {
      console.log(offers[index].OfferName)
    }
  })
```

Comment: @whenitrainsitpours I had to assume this situation ! Please tell me if it helped or I'll remove my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a custom attribute of an HTML element you have to set it first with element.setAttribute().

And to get the attribute you can use the event obj in the click listener:
event.target.getAttribute("OfferName")

link to codepen: https://codepen.io/QwertyG01/pen/NWjqjZj

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

CSS

```
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Javascript

```
var list = document.getElementById("list");

var array = ["test1","test2","test3"]

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
  var element = document.createElement("li");
  var image = document.createElement("img");
  
  image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydOhw.jpg";
  image.setAttribute("OfferName", array[i]);
  image.addEventListener("click",(event)=>{
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute("OfferName"));
  });
  
  element.appendChild(image)
  list.appendChild(element);
}
```